# Sequence convergence

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$\langle a_n \rangle=\langle 1,1,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},...\rangle$ be a sequence of Real numbers.

For the given statement, does $\langle a_n \rangle$ has infinite limit points? Does the sequence has infinite number of convergent subsequences?

**My try**

Well, i was confused on seeing the recurring 1/2 and 1/3 terms. But what came to my mind was. The distinct points are of the form $1/n$ where $n\in N$, the set of natural numbers. Since all the unique terms are isolated, this will imply that the sequence does not have infinite limit points.

Only $1$ and $0$ are limit points as limit superior and limit infimum are $1$ and $0$ respectively.

So, the number of convergent subsequences are also finite (this sounds wrong though)

**Edit**

I also just remembered, a point is a limit point if all open neighbourhood around that point contain a tail. **All but finitely many terms**

Comment: I believe your definition of a limit point is incorrect. That's the definition of a limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is quite good, but you seem to think that (e.g.) $1$ is not a limit point of the sequence $1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, \dots$. This is not correct. I think with this fixed, you'll be able to answer the question.

The standard definition of a limit point is that $x$ is a limit point if for all $\varepsilon > 0$, the set of elements of the sequence inside of $(x - \varepsilon, x + \varepsilon)$ is infinite.

Comment: I am confused. That would mean that every term 1/n is a limit point? And so infinitely many convergent subsequences?

Comment: @user141561: You got it!